# Game does not exist in the namespace Unity.FPS - Building for android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build my game in unity for android and run it to my phone. But for some reason i'm getting some compile erros (that does not exists inside visual studio 2022) on some files (83) and i don't know what is going on wrong.

**Part of my log:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the scripts you've attached to game objects, which are making your enemy work.

Scripts: EnemyController, EnemyManager, EnemyMobile, EnemyTurret, and FollowPlayer seem to be missing a game object or a namespace entry, at the very beginning of the script, right after the entries like `using.System` and so on.

My first guess is you may have written a game object name wrong in those scripts. As you know, C# is case-sensitive. If you wrote game referring to a game object or a namespace, instead of Game, it can cause this problem. My suggestion is to confirm all game object and scene names are referred to correctly in those scripts.

Another, but less likely problem could be that if you were using Rider or a similar kind of coding IDE where the ReSharper extension was installed, and later you copied the code without the namespace entries or to an IDE without ReSharper this may have happened.

The problem is most likely due to a reference mishap in the scripts. So I hope the first step works. Good luck!